# Extending properties in a deep nested prop ImmutableJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, immutable.js

I have an function that accepts `populateKey` as a parameter and this parameter gets passed on and used in my new state named substate. The substate now looks like this: `let subState = _.get(state, "meta.populate." + populateKey);`. Is there any way in Immutable to accomplish the same?

EDIT: I now used this method: see screenshot, but I get "state.updateIn" is not a function. Any reason why that is the case?

[image]

Comment: Please don't post screen shots -- post code.

Comment: I`ll make sure to remember that for future posts Jeremy :)

Comment: What exactly is the problem? It looks okay to me (although the nested `fromJS` seems superfluous).

Comment: I'm insecure if I can use bracket notations like this in Immutable to find my path, instead of the fullpath. I agree, it seems wierd, it was just a "temporary" fix

Comment: The bracket notation is JS syntax, it's evaluated before being handed to Immutable, which just gets a "normal" object as far as it's concerned.

Comment: Indeed, but if this was the other way around, such as isSaving was the key and the value was [action.achievementTypeId] , I´d still be left with the same question :/

Comment: --> If I wanted to use Immutable.setIn([]) manually, of course

Comment: You mean `setIn([ action.achievementTypeId, 'isSaving' ], true)`?

Comment: Okay, lets do it this way. If I wanted to add an value at the end of a property, could I do this?  state.setIn(["meta", "populate"], populateKey => populateKey)

Comment: Meaning, the end result would be `state.meta.populate.populateKey`

Comment: Or Could I use setIn directly on the prop? `state.setIn(['meta', 'populate', 'populateKey'])` ---> would populateKey be valid in this use case? The structure I´m trying to convert is: `_.get(state, "meta.populate." + populateKey);`

Comment: Can you edit your question and add what it is that you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: I´m having a function with takes populateKey as an argument and my new variable substate accepts that, as a part of the extended property

Comment: Updated the question now, @robertklep

Answer (score 1):

There's [`Map#getIn()`](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/getIn):

```
// Example state
let state = Immutable.fromJS({ meta : { populate : { someKey : { some : 'value' } } } });

// Get the substate
let populateKey = 'someKey';
let subState    = state.getIn([ 'meta', 'populate', populateKey ]); // Map { "some" : "value" }
```

This obviously assumes that `state` is an Immutable object and that any changes to it are also propagated throughout your app as Immutable objects.

Comment: state also comes from a parameter, should I just write it like this? `state.setIn(["meta", "populate", populateKey])` ?

Comment: with other words, I cannot change the state within the function except add a property to it

Comment: I added the `state` just to give an example, I assumed that in your actual use case it gets passed. In terms of Immutable, you don't really add a property to it, you create a new state object with an extra property using `setIn()`.

Comment: so if I do newState = state.setIn(...) `state` gets updated and if I use `getin` state will be as it was?

Comment: even though I declare a new object, the actual state gets updated

Comment: `state.setIn()` takes the current contents of `state`, sets a new value, _and returns a new object_. It does not update the object that the old `state` variable points to.

Comment: so there´s no reason not to use `set` when initializing a new value then

Comment: anyhow. I´m using `state.updateIn(["meta", "populate"], x => x.set(propertyKey)` but I get that updateIn is undefined/not a function. Any reason why?

Comment: `state` isn't an Immutable object?

Comment: Yes, why shouldn't it be?

Comment: Because otherwise you would expect `state.updateIn` to be defined (I don't know for which Immutable types that method exists, but I assume that `state` is an `Immutable.Map` which should certainly have [`.updateIn()`](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/updateIn)).

Comment: Indeed, so it should be valid!